# Find the upper value and lower value of a row using match function in excel

Tags: excel

Hi I am trying to find the upper and lower limit of the values in a row using MATCH function, I don't want to use VBA for this. My requirement is as if I give a value the function should return the lower value and upper value from a specific row.

For example, row values are defined in a row as: `100, 115, 200, 267, 392, 420, 487, 499, 520, 550`. If I used the MATCH function to get the lower value but am not getting the upper value what is wrong I am doing. The function I used is:

- To get the lower value

  ```
  =INDEX($A$1:$J$1,MATCH(I10,$A$1:$J$1,1))
  ```

  this works good if I give the value as 118 as search criteria it returns "115"
- To get the upper value

  ```
  =INDEX($A$1:$J$1,MATCH(I10,$A$1:$J$1)+1,1)
  ```

  this formula is suppose to return 200 if I give the search as "118"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$J$1,MATCH(I10,$A$1:$J$1,1)+1)
```